# What effect does precedence have on background task execution?

Tags: bash, background-process

The two examples I have are:

```
echo hi &
```

And:

```
(echo hi &)
```

The first will give me the process id as a return result (e.g. `"[1] 5627"`), where adding precedence operators removes this. What is occurring to cause this ?

Also, is there a way to add precedence yet still have background tasks report their process id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question about *job control*. Please read the corresponding section is `man bash`.

In a shell parenthesis are more than precedence operators. They fire up a new (sub-)shell.

You usually type in an interactive shell with job control enabled. Putting a command in parenthesis runs this command in a subshell without job control.

Try:

```
sleep 10&
jobs

(sleep 10&)
jobs
```

The first sleep is listed by `jobs`, as it is started from a job control enabled shell. The second one is not, because it was started by the subshell.